# Repeated index when using while loop inside windows application form in C++ .NET

Tags: .net, c++-cli

(Updated the code)I am trying to develop a GUI that displays the result of 5 different functions. All functions gets the same input from the for loop and but runs in parallel task to display the results. The results seems to be weird. Instead of displaying 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ... i m getting 1, 1, 3, 4, 4...

```
int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{   
Application::EnableVisualStyles();
Application::SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false); 
Application::Run(gcnew mainform());
return 0;
}
bool flag;
public ref class mainform : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
{
public:
mainform(void)
{
 InitializeComponent();
}
public:typedef Tuple<int, CancellationToken> tuple_t;
private:
System::Void btnStart_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e)
{
int i=0;
while (i < max) {
    auto tuple = gcnew tuple_t(i,CancellationToken);
    task1 = gcnew Task(gcnew Action<Object^(this,mainform::opera1),tuple,CancellationToken);                      
    task1->start(); 
    task1->ConfigureAwait(flag); 
    flag=false; 
    i++;
}
}
public: delegate void add_row_item_det(int data,  int output, DataGridView^ dataGrid);
public: void update_add_row_item_det(int data,  int output,  DataGridView ^dataGrid)
{
    array<String^> ^row = gcnew array<String^> {Convert::ToString(data), Convert::ToString(output)};
    dataGrid->Rows->Insert(0,row);
    dataGrid->Refresh();
}
void opera1(Object^ state)
{
auto tuple = static_cast<tuple_t^>(state);
int data = tuple->Item1;    
CancellationToken token = tuple->Item2;
dataGrid->Invoke(gcnew add_row_item_det(this,&mainWindow::update_add_row_item_det),data,output_data, dataGrid);                             
flag=true;
}
};
```

I expected the output of opera1 as 
1, out1(1)
2, out1(2)
3, out1(3)
4, out1(4)

But the result was
1, out1(1)
1, out1(1)
3, out1(3)
4, out1(4)

Why am i getting the repeated index when i use while loop inside the application?.. is there any way i can make it work as i expected?. Please help me with an example.

%Additional comments:This is the replica of my actual code. I am trying to print integer from the while loop and correspinding output of the integer from a parallel task on a datagrid box. The printed integer are not in series. I could see few repeated integers and few missing integers. Why is this problem arising? and how can i solve this problem? Please help me with some example. Thanks for the help

Comment: I suspect `i` is being passed around by reference somehow. We need to see how `tuple_t` is defined (what's it an alias for, and, more importantly, what's the type of the first template parameter?). It would also be good to see how you're doing the printing.

Comment: Is the first parameter of `tuple_t` defined as `int%`? If not, please post some *real* code.

Comment: Clearly your tuple_t is broken, use `Tuple<int, CancellationToken>` instead.

Comment: Hi all, I posted the replica of the my actual problem as an answer. Please help me to solve the issue.

Comment: @all ::: This is how i defined the tuple_t: public:typedef Tuple<int, CancellationToken> tuple_t;